# Baseboard heater not working despite measuring voltage

Tags: heater, baseboard

I have 240 volts reading on the wire, but heater won't work. I bypassed the thermostat, still won't work.
I don't understand, if the power is there, what could be the issue?

Comment: The resistant(thing that gets hot) wire might be broken.

Comment: The baseboards (2) are new, Stelpro convectors. I tried both of them, including the old one, which was also working. So I am pretty sure they aren't broken. I'm quite baffled.

Comment: I am installing this at a friend's house for his wife. He passed away before finishing it, so I don't know what he did wire-wise in the ceiling, which is now sealed.

Answer (score 17):

A basic electric baseboard heater is a giant toaster. You should be able to measure the resistance of the heater to determine if it is OK. [Ohm's Law](https://ohmslawcalculator.com/ohms-law-calculator) is your friend.

Disconnect the heater from the house and themostat wires. Measure resistance with a multimeter. For example, if it is a 1500W heater then:

Power (1500W) = Voltage (240V) x Current, so current = 6.25A.

Voltage (240V) = Current (6.25A) x Resistance, so resistance = 38.4 Ohms. The number you measure may be different due to a bunch of factors, including the size of the heater - 1500W is typical but smaller and larger are quite common.

What I suspect you will find is infinite resistance - a.k.a., a broken wire.

If you do find a reasonable resistance value then you have to look to the thermostat and/or wiring connections. But my hunch (since you already tried a direct connection without the thermostat) is that the heating element is broken.

Comment: @Scott don't get too hung up on the exact number - you'll never read 38.4Ω when the wire is cold, because resistance changes with temperature.  Infinite (often displayed as "OL") resistance is bad; tens to hundreds of Ohms is good depending on power output; near zero is a short, which isn't the problem you have here (so if you see it there's something up with your measurement). An internal overheat sensor, thermal fuse, or real fuse could also cause an open circuit.

Comment: I am the only one who does not get your math. W=V*I, I=W/V, Ohm= V/I

Comment: @asinine manassehkatz is using the same formula as you, resistance = V/I, they just skip the step of showing it explicitly: 240 V/(6.25 A) = 38.4 Ω.

Answer (score 2):

You will have 240 Volt but a broken heater wire.

Thus no current flowing.

You can verify using a clamp watt meter found in most hardware stores.

There is also the resistance method, but requires the heater wires to be disconnected.

So what the resistance should be ? The fastest method would be to estimate using the Voltage (you know) and divide it by the circuit breaker amps. 240/50 = 4.8 Ohms

Comment: I don't see what measuring wattage would do that just feeling for heat wouldn't. Checking the resistance across the heater seems like a more direct way to check for a broken wire.

Comment: @MichaelMior That is correct, but measuring resistance requires the wires to be disconnected